# Eclipse no inicia en ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

No me inicia Eclipse en Ubuntu. Tengo java instalado:

> ```
> $ java -version
> java version "1.8.0_111"
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
> ```

Error que me sale cuando inicio Eclipse:

> JVM terminated. Exit code=13 /usr/bin/java
>   -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
>   -XX:+UseG1GC
>   -XX:+UseStringDeduplication
>   -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
>   -Xms256m
>   -Xmx1024m
>   -jar /home/***/Descargas/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
>   -os linux
>   -ws gtk
>   -arch x86_64
>   -showsplash /home/***/Descargas/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.6.2.v20161124-1400/splash.bmp
>   -launcher /home/***/Descargas/eclipse/eclipse
>   -name Eclipse
>   --launcher.library /home/***/Descargas/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.401.v20161122-1740/eclipse_1618.so
>   -startup /home/***/Descargas/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
>   --launcher.appendVmargs
>   -exitdata 21000a
>   -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
>   -vm /usr/bin/java
>   -vmargs
>   -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
>   -XX:+UseG1GC
>   -XX:+UseStringDeduplication
>   -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
>   -Xms256m
>   -Xmx1024m
>   -jar /home/***/Descargas/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar

Antes me funcionaba, pero se me rompió la interfaz y tuve que actualizar algunos paquetes de gtk. La verdad no entiendo mucho el error que me sale. He intentado reinstalar Eclipse y sale lo mismo.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Esta no es una pregunta relacionada con programación, probablemente se cierre. Puedes mirar esta solución http://stackoverflow.com/a/27020488/6658955